# C# LP/Lagrange with Bounded Variables

Tags: c#, math, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

**Summary: How would I go about solving this problem?**

Hi there,

I'm working on a mixture-style maximization problem where my variables are going to be bounded by minima and maxima.  A representative example of my problem might be:

```
maximize: (2x-3y+4z)/(x^2+y^2+z^2+3x+4y+5z+10)
subj. to: x+y+z=1
          1 < x < 2
         -2 < y < 3
          5 < z < 8
where numerical coefficients and the minima/maxima are given.
```

My final project is involving a more complicated problem similar to the one above.  The structure of the problems won't change- only the coefficients and inputs will change.  So with the example above, I would be looking for a set of functions that might allow a C# program to quickly determine `x`, then `y`, then `z` like:

```
x = f(given inputs)
y = f(given inputs,x)
z = f(given inputs,x,y)
```

Would love to hear your thoughts on this one!

Thanks!

Comment: Is the denominator in your objective function always positive for all feasible solutions (x,y,z)? I ask, because there is a special purpose algorithm in that case. I doubt whether this is the case in your example, but it often is the case when optimizing a ratio..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard optimization approach for your type of problem, non-linear minimization, is the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm:

- [Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm)

but unfortunately it does not directly support the linear constraints you have added.  Many different approaches have been tried to add linear constraints to Levenberg-Marquardt with varying success.

Another algorithm I can recommend in this situation is the Simplex algorithm:

- [Nelder–Mead method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method)

Like the Levenberg-Marquardt, it also works with non-linear equations but handles linear constraints which act like discontinuities.  This could work well for your case above.

In either case, this is not so much a programming problem as an algorithm selection problem.  The literature is rife with algorithms and you can find C# implementations of either of the above with a little searching.

You can also combine algorithms.  For example, you can do a preliminary search with Simplex with the constraints and the refine it with Levenberg-Marquardt without the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that you want to solve linear programming problems efficiently, you can use [Cassowary.net](http://jozilla.net/Software/CassowaryNet) or [NSolver](http://www.cs.cityu.edu.hk/~hwchun/nsolver/).

If your problem is implementing a linear programming algorithm efficiently, you may want to read [Combinatorial Optimization: Algorithms and Complexity](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486402584) which covers the Simplex algorithm in most of the detail provided in the short text [An Illustrated Guide to Linear Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486262588) but also includes information on the Ellipsoid algorithm, which can be more efficient for more complex constraint systems.

There's nothing inherently C#-specific about your question, but tagging it with that implies you're looking for a solution in C#; accordingly, reviewing the source code to the two toolkits above may serve you well.